# Can a Muslim freelancer develop a movie site for customer?

Tags: halal-haram, business

If a Muslim freelancer is offered a project to program a website which has information about movies and upcoming events (cinema, sports, arts & music), is it Halal for him to accept such a project?

Obviously, the developer of the website won't be organizing or participating in anyway in these events.But these events are not Islamic. Is it Halal to be a programmer for such a website?

P.S. On the other hand, in almost all projects, web developers don't know how their customers use their websites and what kind of (Halal/Haram) ads they host on them.

Comment: Your question is not really appropriate for an academic discussion on Islam. If you are a freelancer, who has found a project in which you have to develop a website, you should do it (by your own consideration). I don't think the purpose of the website is of any relevance. It's a job for you, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, working for the places whose works/activities are Haram, is Haram. 
Totally you must work at the company or other places which their acts are permissible (not to be Haram).

For instance, it would be Haram for a person if he/she works in a company that product beer, because it is a Haram drink.

Or for example, in above-mentioned work, if its movies are not permissible, then it couldn't be Halal...

Eventually, I assume the best person who can recognize that if this is a Halal work or not, is yourself, by paying attention to the base of that job.

Comment: I don't agree. By that logic, work everywhere is haram. Big companies often invest and work with interest. Start up companies often borrow heavily and engage in interest. I highly doubt that working as an accountant at a beer facility counts as haram. And where do you get the idea that movies are not permissible?

Comment: Initially I should say that working as an accountant at a beer facility counts would be considered as a haram practice. how come ? since the person in charge would help the owner of that place in serving people a haram matter. Besides, I assume it would be considered as a haram act from the viewpoint of all different Muslims./ Meanwhile, I didn't mean that all sorts of Movies are haram, haply those kinds which have haram contents and... / thank you mate, for paying attention to those important points.

Comment: Again, I don't agree. An accountant's job in a beer market has nothing to do with beer. It's a white collar job, necessary in today's society and economics. By that logic many jobs are haram because you can relate them to something "haram".  What about someone who sells grapes (to be later used for wine)? What about a farmer who sells wheat(later to be used by beer making process)?  I can argue that MANY jobs leads to haram content embedded in them. Your view simply isn't logical in today's society. You also need to provide more sources for this.

Comment: ur examples are interesting, dear mate. In regard to your examples I agree you that those are not considered as haram things, since they are used in different fields (halal &..). so we cannot say that selling knife is haram, because sb can use it in killing... / actually there is a big difference between selling halal things such as grapes, knifes (also they  could be used in haram..) & being in charge in a job which absolutely is related to selling haram things such as beer/ actually they are 2 separated matters. / I assume Sunni's viewpoint would considered it as a haram act (beer..) /

Comment: Conclusion, perhaps as a general Islamic rule it could be said that working in jobs which could be used in both halal & haram acts (particularly in halal..) won't be haram. But working in the jobs which would be related to haram things is haram (logically and even according to Islam). do u agree dear mate?